# Proper context related substitution for "discuss"

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, you are on the phone and your conversation partner offers something you first need to discuss with somebody else before you can give an answer. I feel like it sounds unnatural to say "I first need to discuss about this and will couple our decision back to you". There must be other expressions to replace "discuss" and "couple back". **My question is:** what would be a more proper, natural sounding version  of what I just mentioned? And can there also be made a distinction between formal and informal?

Comment: couple-back.  I am not sure i know what that means.

Comment: Writing advice is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I need to discuss this with x; I will get back to you."

Or, "I will talk it over with X and call you back."

Both phrases are polite. A married person will often consult the spouse before agreeing with a third person.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! Especially the last one is also good to know.